# DevOps ignore the projects input while dotnet pack

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nuget

I have very strange behavior in a pipeline in DevOps.
First I'll share my pipeline.yml

My **azure-pipeline.yml**

```
trigger:
- nuget

variables:
  BuildConfiguration: "Release"
  ProjectFolder: "MediaAssetSquid.Common"

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Restore packages"
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: "$(ProjectFolder)/**/*.csproj"

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Build with $(BuildConfiguration)"
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: "$(ProjectFolder)/**/*.csproj"
    arguments: "--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)"

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Pack NuGet packages"
  inputs:
    command: pack
    projects: "$(ProjectFolder)/**/*.csproj"
    nobuild: true
    includesymbols: true
    includesource: true
    versioningScheme: "off"

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Push NuGet package'
  inputs:
    command: push
    feedsToUse: select
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: internal
    publishVstsFeed: 'RC-Global-NuGet-Feed'
    versioningScheme: off
```

The restore and build steps run without errors.
And now comes what I don't understand. When packaging, DevOps uses a completely different project.

E.g. while restoring the executed command looks like:

`/usr/bin/dotnet restore /home/vsts/work/1/s/MediaAssetSquid.Common/MediaAssetSquid.Common.csproj --configfile /home/vsts/work/1/Nuget/tempNuGet_81.config --verbosity Detailed`

That is also the expected project path.

And while packaging, DevOps uses the following command:

`/usr/bin/dotnet pack /home/vsts/work/1/s/MediaAssetSquid.Audio.Models/MediaAssetSquid.Audio.Models.csproj --output /home/vsts/work/1/a --no-build --include-symbols --include-source /p:Configuration=Release --verbosity Detailed`

The project `MediaAssetSquid.Audio.Models` does exist, but is located completely somewhere else.

To rule out an error, I have already referenced the project path absolutely like this:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Pack NuGet packages"
  inputs:
    command: pack
    projects: "MediaAssetSquid.Common/MediaAssetSquid.Common.csproj"
    nobuild: true
    includesymbols: true
    includesource: true
    versioningScheme: "off"
```

And here too, DevOps doesn't use the path `MediaAssetSquid.Common/MediaAssetSquid.Common.csproj` but rather this one:

`MediaAssetSquid.Audio.Models/MediaAssetSquid.Audio.Models.csproj`

I have already deleted the pipelines and created new ones. Didn't do anything.

I don't understand why the variable or the absolute project path is not used when packaging.

I have other DevOps projects where everything was okay the way I did it.

Has anyone had a problem like this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is definitely a bug in DevOps.
I clicked on settings in the pack section. Lo and behold, the variable on the right side of the form was missing (see screenshot).

[image]

After I entered the variable manually into the form field and clicked "Add", it went through immediately. Although nothing changed in the Yaml file.

[image]

Cost? A working day.

Comment: According to [DotNetCoreCLI@2 - .NET Core v2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines), `packagesToPack` is required when command = pack.  When command is "pack“, I can reproduce the issue if I use `projects`. But it works fine if I use `packagesToPack`. Not sure why this happens as shown in the first screenshot. But in my test, if I add this task directly through assistant, or I manually change `projects` to `packagesToPack`, the path can be recognized correctly.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't even notice that the property changed from "projects" to "packagesToPack".
Then I don't understand the statement: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines#:~:text=.%20string.-,Required%20when%20command%20%3D%20pack,-.%20Default%20value%3A). Then it's actually a bug. Maybe I'll report this to MS

Comment: This means that if your command is pack, `packagesToPack` is a required parameter. `projects` is required when you use command "build", "restore", "run", "test", "custom" and "publishWebProjects" is "false". In order to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept your answer according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) later. Thanks!